# Docusaurus - getPathsToWatch() causes many recompiles

Tags: docusaurus

I put together a simple Docusaurus plugin that runs when the dev server is started. The plugin returns a `getPathsToWatch()` as described in the [Lifecyle APIs documentation](https://docusaurus.io/docs/lifecycle-apis#getpathstowatch):

```
    return {
        'name': 'docusaurus-plugin-doc',
        getPathsToWatch() { return [`${inPath}/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}`]; },
    };
```

(There's actually only one file that fits that glob pattern, and I've also used an array of one file path string, i.e., no glob pattern.)

File watching works; when I modify a file being watched, Docusaurus re-compiles. However, it continues to recompile about once per second until I stop the dev server.

How can I get Docusaurus to watch the specified files and recompile only once per change?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find it 100% clear from either source, but after poking around the documentation and talking to people on Discord, the issue seems to be the following.

Prior to the `return` statement, I was generating markdown files in /docs. What should be done, instead, is to use the [loadContent](https://docusaurus.io/docs/lifecycle-apis#async-loadcontent) and [contentLoaded](https://docusaurus.io/docs/lifecycle-apis#async-contentloadedcontent-actions) lifecycle methods to generate the content that Docusaurus will consume.